# Error creating a Document with openUntitledDocumentOfType

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I am trying to use the following statement to create a document:

```
id myDocument = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openUntitledDocumentOfType:@"MyClass" display:YES];
```

Nothing is created and `myDocument` is always `nil` despite the fact that `MyClass` is a real class in the project and inherits from `NSDocument`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` in the `openUntitledDocumentOfType:display:` method is the document type name as specified in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in your app's `Info.plist` file, not the name of your document's class.

Specifically, you need to enter the value of the `CFBundleTypeName` key that corresponds to the type of document you want to open. This value is labelled by default in Xcode's property list editor as the `Document Type Name`:

[image: Xcode property list inspector]

It's also editable in the `Document Types` editor in the Info tab of your project settings:

[image]

Comment: Ok it works thanks, but do you know how to pass the type name without specifying it in the .infoplist file? I am opening the application from another app using LaunchApplicationAtUrl, and passing Arguments,and when the app is launched an annoying popup  raise automatically warning that the documentType couldnt be opened, and I think that it is because an internal validation over the CFBundleDocumentTypes against the arguments passed to it.

Comment: You mentioned none of this in your question, and that's a completely different issue. If I answered this question then you should mark the question as answered and ask another question about that issue.